# List view auto size maintain ,Or remove unnecessary list view space

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

This Is My Checkbox Page ,I have separated(Dictionaries,collection,reffrence) using grid ,and each part have a listview ,I want to remove the unnecessary space show in dictionaries section ,Also want to auto increase the size .I have use List View to display checkbox and all section is maintain thought grid

[image]

This Is My Checkbox Page ,I have separated by this list using grid ,I want to remove the unnecessary space show in dictionaries section ,Also want to auto increase the size .I have use List View to display checkbox and all section is maintain thought grid

This Below is my code ,

```
<StackLayout  Padding="10" Grid.Column="0" Orientation="Vertical" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                            
                            <Grid>
                                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        
                                        <RowDefinition Height="3*"/>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="2*"/>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="2*"/>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="3*"/>
                                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>


                                <StackLayout Grid.Row="0"  VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Orientation="Vertical">
                                    <Label Margin="-15,0,0,0"   HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"  Text="{x:Static resources:AppResources.Dictionaries}" Style="{StaticResource MenueLable}" ></Label>

                                    <ListView BackgroundColor="White"  ItemsSource="{Binding DictionariesFilter}" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HasUnevenRows="True"  SeparatorVisibility="None" RowHeight="-1">
                                        <ListView.ItemTemplate >
                                            <DataTemplate >
                                                <ViewCell Tapped="Handle_Tapped" >
                                                    <StackLayout  Orientation="Horizontal">
                                                        <input:CheckBox  Style="{StaticResource CheckBox}" IsChecked="{Binding                                                                  IsChecked}" Type="Check" CheckChangedCommand="{Binding                                                                                      Path=BindingContext.CheckBoxSelectionCommand, Source={x:Reference Name=entriesView}}"/>
                                                        <Label Text="{Binding DicName}" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" ></Label>
                                                    </StackLayout>
                                                </ViewCell>
                                            </DataTemplate>
                                        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                                    </ListView>

                                    <Button  Text="Load More" IsVisible="False"  TextColor="#22B473"  FontAttributes="Bold" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Start"></Button>
                                    <Line Background="#F0F0F0" HeightRequest="2" ></Line>

                                </StackLayout>

                                <StackLayout Grid.Row="1" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" Orientation="Vertical">
                                        <Label Margin="-25,0,0,0" Text="{x:Static resources:AppResources.Collection}" VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"  Style="{StaticResource MenueLable}"></Label>
                                    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding CollectionsFilter}" HasUnevenRows="True"   BackgroundColor="White"  SeparatorVisibility="None" RowHeight="-1" >
                                            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                                                <DataTemplate>
                                                <ViewCell  Tapped="Handle_Tapped">
                                                        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal"  >
                                                        <input:CheckBox Style="{StaticResource CheckBox}" Type="Check" 
                                                           CheckChangedCommand="{Binding  Path=BindingContext.CheckBoxSelectionCommand, 
                                                            Source={x:Reference Name=entriesView}}"/>
                                                        <Label Text="{Binding DicName}" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" ></Label>
                                                    </StackLayout>
                                                    </ViewCell>
                                                </DataTemplate>
                                            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                                        </ListView>
                                        <Line Background="#F0F0F0" HeightRequest="2"></Line>
                                    </StackLayout>

                                    <StackLayout Grid.Row="2"   VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" Orientation="Vertical">
                                        <Label Margin="-20,0,0,0" VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"   Text="{x:Static resources:AppResources.References}"  Style="{StaticResource MenueLable}"></Label>
                                        <ListView HasUnevenRows="True" BackgroundColor="White"  ItemsSource="{Binding RefrencesFilter}" SeparatorVisibility="None" >
                                            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                                                <DataTemplate>
                                                    <ViewCell>
                                                        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal"  >
                                                        <input:CheckBox Style="{StaticResource CheckBox}"  Type="Check" 
                                                           CheckChangedCommand="{Binding  Path=BindingContext.CheckBoxSelectionCommand, 
                                                            Source={x:Reference Name=entriesView}}"/>
                                                        <Label Text="{Binding DicName}" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" ></Label>
                                                    </StackLayout>
                                                    </ViewCell>
                                                </DataTemplate>
                                            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                                        </ListView>
                                        <Line Background="#F0F0F0" HeightRequest="2"></Line>
                                    </StackLayout>
                                <ScrollView Grid.Row="3">
                                    <StackLayout  VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" Orientation="Vertical">

                                        <Label Margin="0,0,0,0" VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"    Text="{x:Static resources:AppResources.CategorisedBy}"  Style="{StaticResource MenueLable}"></Label>

                                        <input:CheckBox Margin="-10,0,0,0" IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected}" Style="{StaticResource CheckBox}" Text="{x:Static resources:AppResources.Categorised_ByCheckBox1}"  Type="Check"   CheckChangedCommand="{Binding  Path=BindingContext.CheckBoxSelectionCommand, 
                                                            Source={x:Reference Name=entriesView}}"/>
                                        <input:CheckBox Margin="-10,0,0,0" Style="{StaticResource CheckBox}" IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected}" Text="{x:Static resources:AppResources.Categorised_ByCheckBox2}"  Type="Check"   CheckChangedCommand="{Binding  Path=BindingContext.CheckBoxSelectionCommand, 
                                                            Source={x:Reference Name=entriesView}}"/>
                                        <input:CheckBox Margin="-10,0,0,0" IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected}" Style="{StaticResource CheckBox}" Text="{x:Static resources:AppResources.Categorised_ByCheckBox3}" Type="Check"   CheckChangedCommand="{Binding  Path=BindingContext.CheckBoxSelectionCommand, 
                                                            Source={x:Reference Name=entriesView}}"/>
                                        <input:CheckBox Margin="-10,0,0,0" IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected}" Style="{StaticResource CheckBox}" Text="{x:Static resources:AppResources.Categorised_ByCheckBox4}" Type="Check"   CheckChangedCommand="{Binding  Path=BindingContext.CheckBoxSelectionCommand, 
                                                            Source={x:Reference Name=entriesView}}"/>


                                    </StackLayout>
                                </ScrollView>
                                   

                                </Grid>


                            </StackLayout>
```

Comment: Have you tried putting `<RowDefinition Height="Auto"` instead of `<RowDefinition Height="3*"` for the first `RowDefinition`

Comment: Yes Sir, When i am try put <RowDefination Height="Auto"> that time it cover whole page ,This Error is occur .But Want This All section's with Auto resize ,What can I do .Please help me .